# How can I set the range of a secondary axis using ggvis::scaled_value()?

Tags: r, ggvis

### Minimal reproducible problem

I can create a secondary axis like the following:

```
ggvis(mtcars, x = ~disp, y = ~mpg) %>%
  add_relative_scales() %>%
  scale_numeric("x", name = "foo", domain = c(0, 600), range = 300) %>%
  add_axis("x", scale = "foo", offset = 50, grid = FALSE)
```

But, it seems that `range` can only be a numeric vector (of length 1 or 2) or a literal `"width"`.

I thought I could write something using `scaled_value()`, like:

```
ggvis(mtcars, x = ~disp, y = ~mpg) %>%
  add_relative_scales() %>%
  scale_numeric("x", name = "foo", domain = c(0, 600), range = scaled_value("x_rel", 0.3)) %>%
  add_axis("x", scale = "foo", offset = 50, grid = FALSE)
```

... but I get `Error: x is not a numeric or integer vector`.

The examples in `help(add_legend)` (controlling `x` and `y` with `scaled_value`s) and the text in `help(scaled_value)` ("These are for use with legends and axes") suggest to me that I ought to somehow be able to specify the `range` of a secondary axis in something other than pixels (or a literal `"width"` or `"height"`).

I've probed around in `add_axis` and `axis_props` but I can't for the life of me figure out how else this ought to work.

Thanks for any and all insights!

### My immediate use case for this

... is a series of stacked area charts where the primary y-axis is GHG emissions in MMTCO2eq (for scientists), the x axis is the year (1990–2050), and the secondary y axis — on the right — is the value relative to the 1990 total, expressed as a percentage (for policymakers).

In California, AB 32 sets GHG targets for 2020, 2030, and 2050 as percentages of the 1990 total. I overlay a trajectory through these targets using a secondary scale, and I would like to draw a secondary axis from 0% to 100%.

For example, if the 1990 total were 66.7 MMTCO2eq, then I think I would want `range = c(scaled_value("y_rel", 1.0), scaled_value("y", 66.7))` for the secondary scale (which the secondary axis would reference).